# Is it possible to customize keyboard shortcuts in IE?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer

There is a webapp which uses Java & ActiveX and it gladly accepts most keyboard shortcuts, but IE will intercept certain ones like F3 and Ctrl+Shift+F.

Can IE keyboard shortcuts be changed or disabled in some setting or file somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In the [JQuery hotkeys docs](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) the venerable John Resig states that IE will, "let you handle built-in short-cuts, but will add their functionality after your code has executed."

Could the app be receiving the keystrokes in addition to IE?

Comment: This may be true for JQuery stuff, but regular HTML accesskeys will not be executed if they match a shortcut in IE. For example, alt-d selects the address bar, so you can't use accesskey='d' for any HTML form buttons or links.